# How to sort Integer Stream using queue? Lab JAVA

Tags: java, sorting, integer, queue, modulo

Okay so this program needs to separate a stream of integers using a queue. I get an output but it's not in the desired order which is firstly integers divisible by 3 then 1%3 then 2%3
Any suggestions?
Here is my code:

```
  import java.util.Random;

  public class Oct22
{

    public static void main(String[] arg)
   {
          int x;
       Random rnd =  new Random();
     Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayQueue<Integer>();
Queue<Integer> queue2 = new ArrayQueue<Integer>();
     //for(char c='a'; c<= 'z'; c++)
    //   queue.add(c);

for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
  queue2.add(rnd.nextInt(100));


for(int i=0;i<queue2.size();i++)
{
 x=queue2.remove();
if(x%3==0)
  queue.add(x);
else
  queue2.add(x); 
}

for(int i=0;i<queue2.size();i++)
{
 x=queue2.remove();
if(x%3==1)
  queue.add(x);
else
  queue2.add(x);
}
 for(int i=0;i<queue2.size();i++)
{
 x=queue2.remove();
if(x%3==2)
  queue.add(x);
else 
  queue.add(x);     
}


System.out.println(queue.size());
System.out.println(queue2.size());

System.out.println("the size of queue is: " + queue.size());  
while(!queue.isEmpty())
   System.out.print(queue.remove()+ " ");
System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
while(!queue2.isEmpty())
  System.out.print(queue2.remove()+" ");

}
```

}

Comment: Please show a sample input, output and desired output

Comment: the input would be the first queue of 20 random integers. My desired output will separate a stream of  integers into 
a stream consisting of; firstly, the integers which are divisible 
by 3, secondly, the integers equivalent to 1 modulo three, and 
lastly, the integers equivalent to 2 modulo 3. Your program 
should simulate the incoming stream by generating 20 random 
Integers between 0 and 100 and can only use at most 2 queue 
of Integers to solve the problem

Comment: output>   33 45 39 36 21 43 4 37 77 38 31 14 90 71 
---------------------------------

Comment: Is that the input or the output?

Comment: Its supposed to be in order though and it's not, also it's not all 20 integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop, change this :

```
for(int i=0;i<queue2.size();i++)
```

to this :

```
int size = queue2.size();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
```

It is necessary because the size of queue2 keeps changing inside your loops, as you remove and add items.

BTW, the last loop can be replaced with

```
queue.addAll(queue2);
```

since at this point all the remaining numbers in queue2 should have a remainder of 2.

Full code :

```
      int x;
      int size;
      Random rnd =  new Random();
      Queue<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
      Queue<Integer> queue2 = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

      for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        queue2.add(rnd.nextInt(100));

      size = queue2.size();
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
        x=queue2.remove();
        if(x%3==0)
          queue.add(x);
        else
          queue2.add(x); 
      }

      size = queue2.size();
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
        x=queue2.remove();
        if(x%3==1)
          queue.add(x);
        else
          queue2.add(x);
      }

      size = queue2.size();
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
        x=queue2.remove();
        if(x%3==2)
          queue.add(x);
        else 
          queue.add(x);     
      }

      System.out.println(queue.size());
      System.out.println(queue2.size());

      System.out.println("the size of queue is: " + queue.size());  
      while(!queue.isEmpty())
        System.out.print(queue.remove()+ " ");
      System.out.println("\n---------------------------------");
      while(!queue2.isEmpty())
        System.out.print(queue2.remove()+" ");
```

Comment: You are correct! Thank you sir, one other question. When trying to convert the output using toString() how do I keep them in the same order? I'm getting them jumbled up when I convert because Im trying to show in JOptiondialaog box

Comment: `public String toString()
    {
      String output ="";
      for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        output +=buffer[i]+" ";
      return output;
    } `

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome  I don't see where you are creating this `buffer` array, so I can't say where the problem is.